# flex spring jpa hibernate

Tags: java, apache-flex, hibernate, spring, jpa

i search a tutorial or  book a web that make an evidence  a project using flex, spring, jpa, hibernate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used this tutorial "[The Flex, Spring and BlazeDS full stack](http://sebastien-arbogast.com/2008/07/22/the-flex-spring-and-blazeds-full-stack-on-adobe-developer-connection/)" in a previous project. It worked well, but most of the technologies have been updated since, so your mileage may vary.

Or, if you want to use Granite instead of Blaze, this looks pretty good:
"[Getting Started with GraniteDS, Spring, and Maven](http://blog.ericdaugherty.com/2010/01/getting-started-with-graniteds-spring.html)"